# Why does my users get a .ost error message after giving them Full Access to mailbox?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, exchange-server, azure-hybrid-connections

I work in a big company and we have just migrated to office 365 in a hybrid scenario.

**Here is the "stack":**

- Exchange 2016 Hybrid
- ADSync with AADConnect
- Usermailboxes hosted on Office 365
- Users use the Outlook 2016 Client (can't roll out o365 client, because we have over 50.000 users and so many custom outlook plugins 32 Bit)

**We do this as followed:**

Create a new ad user.

`Enable-RemoteMailbox samAccountName -RemoteRoutingAddress samAccountName@tenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com -PrimarySmtpAddress address@tenant.com -shared`

(This also turns of emailAddressPolicy which it should do according to our exchange admins). Our exchange admins are also stuck on that problem so that's why I created this post here)

Then I wait and have a look in the ECP Admin center. Before the sync happens the remote Routing address is: `address@tenant.com`

After the first sync (every 30 minutes) it's `samAccountName@tenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com` ==> How it should be.

**After another 30 minutes (2nd sync back to AD) it's a X500 address.**

When I look it up in PS like `get-remotemailbox <UPN> | fl *remote*` the address is `samAccountName@tenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com` (how it should be).

So it's displayed wrong in the ecp.

### But the huge problem we face is this:

When I give any user from the company full access to this shared mailbox it won't get Automapped.

After 1 hour of waiting I manually add it. When I do this a .OST error comes.

***Error:***

> "Microsoft Outlook cannot expand the folder. The set of folders cannot
>   be opened. The file
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook{username]}.ost"

Also with outlook restart it's not working. So our guess is because something is wrong about ECP and the Remote Routing address.

Please note that this isn't a client problem. It effects almost every mailbox I create these days.

I had another post about this but with fewer details and without the knowledge of the remote routing address: https://www.reddit.com/r/exchangeserver/comments/eceqm6/automapping_doesnt_work_on_hybrid_setting/

Anyone have any ideas? I appreciate any kind of help from you guys. If you need any more informations please ask

Answer (score 0):

You have an Hybrid architecture, ok. You need to use O365, because if you use older versions you will need to change a bit the computer registry in each computer. Or change the on-premise autodiscover.

But your big problem is big indeed. Right now, you can not hare mailboxes in O365 correctly. If you do that, you may have access to main mailbox, but if you use archive, you won't have access (you just have OWA access).

Regards.